# From Python Basics to Tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, menu

I'm learning Tkinter, and this program was part of my last project before going into Tkinter. I would like to know how would this main menu would look in Tkinter.

I was trying to look for something similar but when I made reference to main menu, I usually got main menu as File, Edit, View,...

My ideas is that when you type in 1 - 6, your window is cleared and some other info appears and there is an Exit button and Return button. If I don't make myself clear please tell me. English is not my native language so...

```
print("                %s %s"%(nombre,apellido))
print("               __________________________________ ")
print("              |         Menú principal           |")
print("              | 1.Dato breve sobre mi carrera    |")
print("              | 2.Cursos y tareas                |")
print("              | 3.Grupos de apoyo                |")
print("              | 4.Calendario Academico           |")
print("              | 5.Feriados                       |")
print("              | 6.Salir                          |")
print("              |__________________________________|")
op=int(input("               Elija una opcion:"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here we go.

```
import tkinter as tk


class FirstFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.pack()
        master.title("Menu")
        master.geometry("500x400")
        
        self.but1 = tk.Button(self, text= '1', command=self.opt1)
        self.but1.pack()
    
        self.but2 = tk.Button(self, text= '2', command=self.opt2)
        self.but2.pack()
    
        self.but3 = tk.Button(self, text= '3', command=self.opt3)
        self.but3.pack()
    
        self.but4 = tk.Button(self, text= '4', command=self.opt4)
        self.but4.pack()
    
        self.but5 = tk.Button(self, text= '5', command=self.opt5)
        self.but5.pack()
    
        self.but6 = tk.Button(self, text= '6', command=self.opt6)
        self.but6.pack()
    
    def opt1(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.app = SecondFrame(self.master)

    def opt2(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.app = ThirdFrame(self.master)
    
    def opt3(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.app = FourthFrame(self.master)

   def opt4(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.app = FifthFrame(self.master)

    def opt5(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.app = SixthFrame(self.master)

    def opt6(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.app = SeventhFrame(self.master)
    
class SecondFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.pack()
        master.title("Opt1")
        master.geometry("400x400")
    
        self.opt1lab = tk.Label(self, text = 'This is option 1')
        self.opt1lab.pack()
    
        self.gobackbut1 = tk.Button(self, text = 'Go Back', command =     self.goback1)
        self.gobackbut1.pack()
    
    def goback1(self):
    self.destroy()
    self.app = FirstFrame(self.master)

class ThirdFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.pack()
        master.title("Opt2")
        master.geometry("400x400")
    
        self.opt2lab = tk.Label(self, text = 'This is option 2')
        self.opt2lab.pack()
    
        self.gobackbut2 = tk.Button(self, text = 'Go Back', command = self.goback2)
        self.gobackbut2.pack()
    
    def goback2(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.app = FirstFrame(self.master)


class FourthFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.pack()
        master.title("Opt3")
        master.geometry("400x400")
        
        self.opt3lab = tk.Label(self, text = 'This is option 3')
        self.opt3lab.pack()
    
        self.gobackbut3 = tk.Button(self, text = 'Go Back', command = self.goback3)
        self.gobackbut3.pack()
    
    def goback3(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.app = FirstFrame(self.master)

class FifthFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.pack()
        master.title("Opt4")
        master.geometry("400x400")
    
        self.opt4lab = tk.Label(self, text = 'This is option 4')
        self.opt4lab.pack()
    
        self.gobackbut4 = tk.Button(self, text = 'Go Back', command = self.goback4)
        self.gobackbut4.pack()
    
    def goback4(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.app = FirstFrame(self.master)

class SixthFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.pack()
        master.title("Opt5")
        master.geometry("400x400")
    
        self.opt5lab = tk.Label(self, text = 'This is option 5')
        self.opt5lab.pack()
    
        self.gobackbut5 = tk.Button(self, text = 'Go Back', command = self.goback5)
        self.gobackbut5.pack()
    
    def goback5(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.app = FirstFrame(self.master)
   
class SeventhFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master, **kwargs)
        self.pack()
        master.title("Opt6")
        master.geometry("400x400")
    
        self.opt6lab = tk.Label(self, text = 'This is option 6')
        self.opt6lab.pack()
    
        self.gobackbut6 = tk.Button(self, text = 'Go Back', command = self.goback6)
        self.gobackbut6.pack()
    
    def goback6(self):
        self.destroy()
        self.app = FirstFrame(self.master)

if __name__=="__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    app=FirstFrame(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Yep, I'm trying to make a menu in Tkinter.

Comment: How can I add an exit button in every frame? I'm trying to use sys.exit() (importing sys) but nothing. :(

Comment: So what I have found is when I try to exit the best thing to do is do self.destroy()